# SMS sent to Android Emulator displayed in Chinese chars

Tags: android, unicode, char, sms, emulation

I'm sending a sms to the emulator (using netcat localhost 5554).

If the message contains only ASCII-characters, it is received correctly.

```
 sms send +49123456789 This is fine.
```

But if I use non-ascii chars (which I need for some German chars), the SMS sent with

```
sms send +49123456789 Das ist ärgerlich. This is annoying.
```

is displayed on the Android device in Chinese (?) chars (䠀䐀愀猀 椀猀琀 ̀爀最攀爀氀椀挀栀⸀ 吀栀椀猀 椀猀 愀渀渀漀礀椀渀最).

Language and layout on the device are German.
Any suggestions how Unicode-SMS can be displayed in right way?

Comment: "to the emulator", "on the device" do not match. Please explain better your setup.

Comment: Normal shell:

"nc localhost 5556" and "sms send +49123456789 Das ist ärgerlich. This is annoying."

Now the AVD is receiving this message. But this is how it is displayed:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/2uqbsdl.jpg

Comment: shell of what? You did not explain your setup enough. Atleast I do not understand the scenario.

Comment: The terminal of my computer (bash). On Ubuntu I start it with Ctrl+Alt+t.

Comment: You say "if I use Unicode" then did you chance something in the settings of your shell? If not then you meant "using non ascii characters". Will the shell use utf-8? utf-16? ISO-8859-1? How do you know? If it used utf-8 then only the ä would be different.

Comment: You're right, I have to say "non-ascii chars". I said Unicode because the "(…)message must be utf8(…)". But I think this is not a problem of my terminal, because using another oder telnet instead of netcat, or simply a socket in Python – all of these attempts have the same result.

Comment: How do you read the input with the android app? Where do you display it? Is that your app? You still did not tell your setup.

Comment: The SMS-App which you can see in the screenshot is the standard SMS/MMS-App on Android.
I did not change anything else then the language (English → German). Just started the emulator with a brand new AVD (Android 4.4.2) and sent a sms to this device. (As already said, connecting to localhost 5556 (or 5554, depends on which port the AVD is started) and sending a sms to the device with "sms send number message".)

Comment: It can be the shell, it can be the sms program or the adv. Where to start? Why are you testing this in this way? You have no real 4.4 device?

Comment: No, I don't have a real device, just the avd. I start the emulator the normal way ("~/adt-bundle-linux-x86…/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Name_of_Android_Device"). Then I send a sms to the device connecting to the port and using the "sms send"-command. (In the end I will do this in python, but as I already said, it makes no difference whether I use python, netcat or telnet.)

Comment: In the end you will use python. I dont understand. Would you continue using it with python? And the AVD? Ehhhh... whats the purpose? Im puzzled.

Comment: I will send SMS to an AVD (to the emuluator). My framework is written in python – but it makes nothing else than connecting to port 5554 on localhost and use the "sms send"-functionality of the emulator. So it makes no difference if you try it with python, nc or telnet, the receiving message always looks the same. So it's probably a error on the Android device.

Comment: You still did not explain the purpose of all this. Of course programming is nice. But when you are done then for what can you use it?

Comment: I still do not understand the purpose. For what can it be used? I don't know how to connect with nd? to an emulator. And then opening a command promt window (windows 7) to send that string? Maybe I'm going to try that soon but then still: even when it works for what is it usefull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, non-ascii chars may be replaced by their unicode representation.

```
 sms send +49123456789 Das ist \u00E4rgerlich. This is annoying.
```

This will be received and displayed in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

That is not Unicode message ä is supported in gsm7 encoding and you can encode it like: 7B. If you use HTTP encode it like %7B.